# MySQL How to automatically insert different values into a table

Tags: mysql

Let me describe to you my problem. Let´s say I have attribute_id´s with id (82, 93, 284, 343, 432, 537). 
My table has those columns (id, rule_id, attribute_id, _position, required)

Now, I want to insert few more rows that got those specifics:
-id will change automatically - no issue
-rule_id is always the same, will be defined by variable - no issue
-attribute_id will change, sometimes it will be (82, 93, 432 - 3 rows) or (343, 284, 537, 82, 93 - 5 rows) - here is the main problem
-_position will start with 1 and end with 1 + number of rows. - no issue
-required always value 0. -no issue

I dont want to always write:

```
INSERT INTO ind_rule_attribute (rule_id, attribute_id, _position, required)
VALUES (rule_id_"var", 82, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO ind_rule_attribute (rule_id, attribute_id, _position, required)
VALUES (rule_id_"var", 93, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO ind_rule_attribute (rule_id, attribute_id, _position, required)
VALUES (rule_id_"var", 432, 3, 0);
```

Rather I would like to use somehow loop so that I would fill only let´s say
82, 93, 432 - probably into a variable - so the code would do the work for me. 
This is my first question here so sorry if I made any mistakes in my description but I couldn't find answer here or searching on google.

Comment: You want to generate multiple sql insert statements based on the number of attribute_ids and a single rule_id?

Comment: rule_id is the same for all rows. the number of insert statements is based on a number of attributes I want to insert

Comment: How would such a routine get the attributes - do you intend to supply them directly or are they coming from a table or a query?

Comment: We have set another table with attributes with numbers from 1 to 250. So what I need to do is add a row to a different table that connects attribute table with yet another table. I am not honestly sure how I would be able to describe to you our setup to a full extent but what I need to do is to add rows to this **connecting table**.

Comment: I am not clear how this hangs together. It could be that a trigger would do or a procedure..

Answer (score 0):

You can use PreparedStatement if using JDBC or Native Query using JPA
INSERT INTO ind_rule_attribute (rule_id, attribute_id, _position, required)
VALUES (rule_id_"var", ?1, ?2, ?3);

```
then set prepStatment.setParameter(1, value1);
then set prepStatment.setParameter(2, value2);
then set prepStatment.setParameter(3, value3);
```

If you are inserting values directly into DB using mysql client utility, then you need to write a storedprocedure that will help in setting values in variables.

Comment: I am using HeidiSQL

Comment: What are using in front-end? like Java JDBC, PHP PDO or Perl DBI

Comment: prepared statement in Java using JDBC:
java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = 
connection.prepareStatement(
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE EMAIL = ?");
stmt.setString(1, email);
stmt.executeQuery();

prepared statement in PHP using PDO:
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM 
                         table WHERE EMAIL = ? ");

$stmt->execute($email);

prepared statement in Perl using Perl DBI:
my $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM 
                                table WHERE EMAIL = ?');

$stmt->execute($email);

Comment: I will consult that with my colleges. I am a beginner with mySQL and I have been doing only the most basic stuff. But as I said this might help, but I will have to show that someone when I am in an office.